# Assertion failure when delete rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I delete row in tableview,I am getting the following exception:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1716
```

And here's part of my code:

```
[self.feedListView.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.feedListView.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ atIndexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.feedListView.tableView endUpdates];
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove feedToDelete from self.allFeeds:

```
[self.feedListView.tableView beginUpdates];
NSMutableArray *array = [self.allFeeds mutableCopy];
[array removeObject:feedToDelete];
self.allFeeds = array;
[self.feedListView.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ atIndexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.feedListView.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I put the code in another place.It works!Thank you so much!